# Bootstrap Fixed Table Cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I use Bootstrap to make a fixed table cell, with bootstrap.overflow hidden? I have tried this, one but data is going vertically down:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table th,
table td {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have 10 columns and style like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="mbhead">
        <tr class="mbrow">
            <th style="width:10px"></th>
            <th style="width:10%;">A</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">B</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">C</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">D</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">E</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">F</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">G</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">H</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">I</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">J</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        //other contents...
        </body>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried , that help other users as well in detail when they have the same issue as yours .

Comment: also post a jsfiddle or more code so that we can reproduce the issue you are having ..

Comment: @Amrendra : Please Make a fiddle for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is what you want. I have used div. Let me know if it helps.
You can see that i have used 2 divs. In first div i set to overflow hidden

```
<div  style="overflow: hidden; margin-left: 20px; height: 504px;">
```

inside this div i have used another div

```
 <div id="product"  style="overflow: auto;height: 350px;">
```

The link to fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JBs8g/7/)

Answer (score 0):

overflow: hidden only works on block level elements so you can either make your TH and TD elements display: block or (probably better) put a div insisde them set overflow: hidden on the DIVs.

Here's an example showing display: block set on the TD/TH: http://jsfiddle.net/YB4yU/

```
th, td {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the css property white-space to "nowrap"

```
table th, table td { overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap }
```